# primefaces can I load a css isn't folder resources?

Tags: css, primefaces

I work in a project with the following structure

[image]

I want to override the default styles primefaces with my own css.

I use in my xhtml

```
<f:facet name="last">
 <h:outputStylesheet library = "css" name="estilosprimefaces.css" />

 </f:facet>
```

Can I use the css in webContent/css or do I have to move these css to resources folder?

**EDITED**

```
<f:facet name="last">

   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"       
        href="/copernico/estilos/nwrenfe.css" />

 </f:facet>
```

**EDITED**

```
<h:body>
 <f:facet name="last">

         <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Fecha Desde4:" />

         </f:facet>





    <div id="container">
        <div id="header">
            <ui:insert name="header">
            // header content
         </ui:insert>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
            <ui:insert name="content">
            </ui:insert>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <ui:insert name="footer">
            </ui:insert>
        </div>
    </div>
</h:body>
```

Comment: Short answer: Yes... Longer answer: Sure, use the plain html stylesheet tag and not the jsf one... And also read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used/11988418?noredirect=1#comment59117513_11988418

Comment: I tried with the tag link but it doesn't load the sheet css. I edited my question with the new code

Comment: Put some other text in that facet and see if that IS displayed. Most likely the facet is just not processed there

Comment: The facet last is in a template.xhtml. I modified it . Edited the code. The new label is not displayed

Comment: Do you actually know what a facet is/does and where they can be used?

Comment: I don't know how to use the facet last

Comment: Maybe you don't need the facet here just the stylesheet.

Comment: I don't want to apply default  primefaces styles, I want to use my css styles

Comment: Where did I say you should not use your own stylesheet...

Comment: My own css styles aren't in folder resource. How can I apply my own stylesheet?

Comment: With a plain html stylesheet mechanism... wow

Comment: What is a plain html stylesheet mechanism ?

Comment: You already used that in one of your edits above. Please consult your team (the ones that 'know' using a template is not SPA)